# .NET Extension methods on constructed types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, intellisense, extension-methods

I was experimenting in order to create a little compile-safe helper for mapping between classes.

```
public class A : IMappableTo<B>, IMappableTo<A>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IMappableTo<T>
{
}

public static class ExtensionTest
{
    public static T MapTo<T>(this IMappableTo<T> source)
    {
        return default(T); // this does not mind, just for demo purposes
    }
}
```

The intent was to create an extension method able to detect not implemented maps (at compile time).

It worked as expected, but with an unexpected issue.

```
public static void test()
{
    // compiler doesn't complain, but intellisense can't autocomplete it.
    var case1 = new A().MapTo<A>().MapTo<B>(); 
    var case2 = new A().MapTo<string>(); // compiler complains, as intended
}
```

So well, **it does compile and work**, but **Visual Studio** (tested with 2015/2017) is **unable to autocomplete the extension method**. I did some additional tests and it seems to be produced by the fact that class A implements two IMappableTo constructed interfaces. If I remove one, the autocomplete simply works again.

Any idea of how to fix this behaviour or rewrite the code in a manner that cause no further troubles?

Comment: But it does compile if `A` implements both interfaces? I wonder which constructed version of the extension will be called at runtime....

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, it compiles and works as expected. Seems like a corner case for the intellisense.

Comment: Just tried it, it does compile, but if you want to _use_ the extension you have to provide the generic argument, like `(new A()).MapTo<A>();` or `(new A()).MapTo<B>();`. Well, I don't know why IntelliSense doesn't support this.

Comment: @RenéVogt The constraints work this way, I am now trying to rewrite it in a manner that Intellisense can make use of it. Thanks for helping.